# Keeping reference to actor system

Tags: java, akka, embedded-jetty

I have a desktop application with embedded jetty and some SWING UI in Java.
I want to utilise akka for sending messages from embedded jetty servlets to my application classes ( with ability for actor to update swing UI on incoming message).
As i understand i need to have single actor system for the whole application. The question is what is the best approach to handle reference to it? 
Should i make some sort of singleton that wraps reference to actor system ?
Can there be an issue with classloaders as jetty might use it's own classloader ?

Comment: I don't understand from your description what the servlet container is doing; who or what connects and sends what to that servlet container and how does that related to the swing application?

Answer (score 0):

In general with servlets you would decide if you want an actor system per jvm, or per embedded server instance, or per web application. Most people for a normal use case would want an actor system per web application. In which case they would subclass `ServletContextListener`, create the actor system, then get the `ServletContext` from the `ServletContextEvent` and add the actor system as an attribute. Then in servlets and servlet filters you can lookup the actor system from the servlet context. In general though folks starting out with a new project should be looking at the [Play](http://www.playframework.com/) else the [Socko](http://sockoweb.org/) web frameworks which are built to work well with Akka out of the box.

In your case you are talking about embedding the servlet container and asking about classloading. Servlet containers do 'parent last' classloader semantics. If the akka classes are not in a jar in the war we would expect them to be loaded from the main application classpath. If your building with something like maven you could mark shared libraries of the the web project dependencies as 'provided' so that you war classes compile against them but they doing get packaged into the war file. Then if your classes in the webapp use those library classes they could come from the main classpath which can be shared with any code which is not running in the webapp.

If you are actually using the web container simply to dynamically redeploy code then its probably the wrong tool of the job. Use an osgi container instead. Here is a link to some code where it dynamically redeploys business logic using osgi https://github.com/simbo1905/osgi-extensible There are several good osgi enterprise spec containers that sample code uses felix but there are others. The only reason today to use a servlet container is to serve up web pages using jsp like technology. Akka has remote messaging and the like and works very well with HTML5 websockets without needing a servlet container. You can use the Socko webserver which is written in Akka to host your akka business logic and use json to message to it without the bloat of a full servlet container. Here is a link to some code which does that https://github.com/simbo1905/sprint-planning